# Form validation not working properly: name remains unfilled

Tags: php, validation, forms

I am very new to PHP. I have this very basic form on which I'm trying to add very basic validation. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, But once I submit my form with every field filled, it's not going to another page. It is displaying name as unfilled field.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if($_POST['submit'])
{
$error=array();
$n=$_POST['name'];
$p=$_POST['password'];
    if($n == '');
    {
        $error[0]= "Please fill a name";
    }
    if($p == '')
    {
        $error[1]= "Password is required";
    }

}
?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="<?php  if($_POST['submit']) { if(count($error)<1) { echo "hello.php"; } else { echo ''; } } ?>">
<div>
<span>Username:</span> <input type="text" name="name" id="user" /> <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $error[0];?> </span>
</div>
<div>
<span>Password:</span><input type="password" name="password" id="pass" /><span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $error[1];?> </span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" />
</div>
</form>
</html>
```

Now Even When I submit The form with every field filled I get name field is not filled!
It might be something stupid, But I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Max see the updated answer. it will solve the problem which you describe in your comment thanks for accepting the answer. if any problem. just msg me again. i will reply you again. means will update my answer. here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if($n == '');` remove **;** from this line it should be this

```
if($n == '')
```

**This is what you ask in your comment.** 
**//Instead of coding the action. in form you should check for the $error messages if they are empty. you can direct user to hello.php. Thanks**

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
if($_POST['submit'])
{
$error=array();
$n=$_POST['name'];
$p=$_POST['password'];
    if(empty($n))
    {
        $error[0]= "Please fill a name";
    }
    if(empty($p))
    {
        $error[1]= "Password is required";
    }
    if(empty($error))
    {
        header('Location:hello.php');
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<span>Username:</span> <input type="text" name="name" id="user" /> <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $error[0];?> </span>
</div>
<div>
<span>Password:</span><input type="password" name="password" id="pass" /><span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $error[1];?> </span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" />
</div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: That sure was an embarrassing Mistake! But still i have to click submit button twice to submit my form! Any idea why that could be?

Comment: I had to press two submits because i was using two isset($_POST['submit']) in my code! I removed it and now it's working fine! Thank's for every body's help! It's a great community!

Comment: You are mostlikely to get problems with the `header()` like this.

Comment: @SuperDJ What do you mean?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 1) You wrote it as 1 single string with no space between the `:` and the url. 2) You don't use `exit()` to prevent code from executing after the redirect. 3) If the headers are already send you will get an error message.

Comment: @superDJ what you are saying i should give exit in else statement ?

Comment: @Max i did not read your comment before. I just read them now. so it solved nice to know Thanks bye

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 If you look at my answer you will see what I mean

Comment: @SuperDJ i do understand it now. And i learn some thing thanks for that. but i still beleiv this is not the right time for OP to go in there so i will not update my answer. But thanks i learn some thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your php use the following:

```
<?php
function errors($error) {
    echo '<ul> class="error"';
    foreach($error as $fail) {
        echo '<li>'.$fail.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

// Sanitize user input
function sanitize($value) {
    // You need to pass your db connection to mysqli functions.
    // You can do this by setting it as a paramater to the function or include a file with the connection in the function (not really recommended)
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, trim(strip_tags($value)));
}

//redirect a user
function to($url) {
   if(headers_sent()) {
       echo '<script>window.location("'.$url.'");</script>';
   } else {
       header('Location: '.$url);
       exit();
   }
}

// The code is only tiggered when the page is posted
if($_POST) {
    $error = array(); // store all errors
    $name = sanitize($_POST['name']);
    $pass = sanitize($_POST['password']);

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)) {
        // continue with more validation
    } else {
        $error[] = 'You didn\'t enter a username and or password';
    }

    if(!empty($error)) {
        echo errors($error);
    } else {
        // if there are no errors (forexample log the user in)
        to('hello.php');
    }
}
?>
```

And as your html this is enough:

```css
<style>
.error ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.error ul li {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <span>Username:</span> <input type="text" name="name" id="user">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Password:</span> <input type="password" name="password" id="pass">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

Some usefull links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use php  function empty() like

```
if(empty($n)){
$error[0]= "Please fill a name";
}
```